# Sequentially execute two functions with jQuery in for loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm pretty new to Javascript. Please don't make it too harsh :)

I have two functions, both of which involve executing jQuery requests within for loops. For example,

```
function a(n,locations) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
      data: {
        searchtext: input,
        app_id: APP_ID,
        app_code: APP_CODE,
      },
      success: function (data) {
        handleData(data,locations);
      }
   });
 }
```

The `handleData()` function would make changes to the empty array `locations` from the jQuery data. My function `b(m)` is of similar format but would use the updated locations as input.

Now, I have a `c(n,m)` in which I would like execute `a()` and `b()` sequentially:

```
function c(n,m) {
  var locations = [];
  a(n,locations);
  b(m,locations);
}
```

From previous answers I understand that sequentially executing functions involving jQuery calls can be achieved by using promises (such as `.then`). However, this solution is only applicable when `a(n)` returns a promise, which is not achievable under the for-loop structure. Could you please share your insights on how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Aren't you already running your two functions sequentially? Function `c` will run `a`, `a` will go through the `for` loop, then once the `for` loop has finished, `b` will launch. Is that not what you want?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Sorry that was me being unclear. In `a` I would like to update an array `locations` whose updated version I would like to use in `b`.

Comment: Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [recursion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/recursion-javascript) instead of your `for` loop. For example, you can call the function `recursionExample` like this,

```
function a(n) { 
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) {
    (function recursionExample(a) { 
      if (a === n) {
          resolve;
      } else {
          $.ajax({ url: 'https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json', 
          type: 'GET', 
          dataType: 'jsonp', 
          jsonp: 'jsoncallback', 
          data: { 
              searchtext: input, 
              app_id: APP_ID, 
              app_code: APP_CODE, 
          }, 
          success: function(data) { 
            handleData(data);
            recursionExample(a + 1);
          } 
        }); 
      }
    })(0);
  });
}
```

This will then allow you to use the `promise` and `.then` functions. Like so...

```
function c(n,m) { 
    var locations = []; 
    a(n,locations)
    .then (function() {
        b(m,locations); 
    });
}
```